# TranslateY animation bugging

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I have a box that I would like to expand (100% height) after click, and then collapse and stick to bottom. I made a function (vue framework structure) to run the animation, but unfortunately it keeps on bugging.. how do I make it more smooth and less buggy? Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yakq2e01/).

JS:

```
animate() {
        let height_ = window.innerHeight - this.$refs.box.getBoundingClientRect().top
        if(!this.revealed) {
          event.target.style.maxHeight = '100%';
          event.target.style.transform = 'translateY(0px)'
          this.revealed = true
        }
        else if(this.revealed) {
          console.log(height_)
          event.target.style.maxHeight = height_ - 570 + 'px'
          event.target.style.transform = 'translateY(570px)'
          this.revealed = false
        }
      }
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 30% 32% 16% 22%;
    grid-template-columns: 47% 29% 24%;
  }
.section__extra {
    grid-area: 1 / 3 / 5 / 2;
    background-color: black;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
    left: -2vw;
    transform: translateY(570px);
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.3s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
    transition: all 1.3s cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1);
  }
```

Comment: It's kinda "2 uneven bezier curve" there don't cancel each outer out. You have to options, take a look on transform-origin and let it expand from the bottom that way, or you could go the javascript route and cancel the animation out perfectly, take a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YdvQPkJd0gc if you want to go the javascript route.

Comment: or, why not slide it up from the bottom

Comment: Then how do I slide up from the bottom? Should I change `transform-origin Y`?

Comment: I would not touch the max height property, just let it overflow the screen and animate translateY as you are doing

Comment: But the height of a box is set to specific value and then after `click` I need it to be 100% vh, using `translateY` allows only to move the box.

Comment: The hight should always be set to 100vh, height is expensive to animate as well, it requires both layout and paint

Comment: addition to my last comment - https://csstriggers.com/max-height

Comment: So leaving alone the height, I managed to create the animation using `translateY` only. The problem is that my box should stick to the bottom and it does thanks to `box.style.maxHeight = window.innerHeight - this.$refs.box.getBoundingClientRect().top` but without height manipulation I cannot change it from being 300px high at the start and at the end being 100%

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183456/discussion-between-benjaco-and-kabugh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue was to not animate 2 radical different properties with a none linear curve.
The solution ended up with always having the box at 100vh, hide the overflow, and only animate the transform. (Which also is better for the performance).
See the comment thread for more information.